# Non-isomorphic elliptic curves with the same j-invariant.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Two elliptic curves over finite field F with the same j-invariant are isomorphic over the algebraic closure of F. But they do not have to be isomorphic over F itself. I'm looking for example of such situation. 
Here is example for Q:
[J-invariant and isomorphism of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505739/j-invariant-and-isomorphism-of-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbq)
I would like to see example for finite field.
There is no example in Blake-Seroussi-Smart book I own.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your finite field $K$ has characteristic $p\ge5$, then you can always put your elliptic curve in the form
$$ E_{A,B} : Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B. $$
Then as long as $j(E_{A,B})\ne0,1728$, there are exactly two $K$-isomorphism classes of elliptic curves with that $j$-invariant, namely $E_{A,B}$ and $E_{c^2A,c^3B}$, where $c$ is a quadratic non-residue in $K$, i.e., $c$ represents the non-trivial element in $K^*/(K^*)^2$. For $j=0,1728$, it's a bit more complicated, you'll get non-isomorphic twists for each element of $K^*/(K^*)^6$, $K^*/(K^*)^4$, respectively. And for $p=2$ and $3$, it's even more complicated. In any case, this is all covered in the theory of *twists* of elliptic curves, see for example Chapter X, Section 5, of my *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Comment: I'm very honored to obtain an answer from You, Mr Silverman. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You welcome. You might also want to look at my answer to the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505739/j-invariant-and-isomorphism-of-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbq/3668522#3668522

Answer (score 4):

As for $\Bbb{Q}$ take the quadratic twist $$y^2=x^3+ax+b\mapsto dy^2=x^3+ax+b$$
with $d$ not a square. Both curves are the same over $F(\sqrt{d})$.