# How can we decide two elliptic curves over Q are isomorphic over Q?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

How can we decide which of the following elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$?
$$E_1:y^2=x^3+1$$
$$E_2:y^2=x^3+2$$
$$E_3:y^2=x^3+x+1$$

Comment: This question has already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505739/j-invariant-and-isomorphism-of-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbq?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Silverman's book and answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3668522/276986) namely given $$E_i/K:y^2=x^3+a_ix+b_i,\qquad a_ib_i\ne 0$$
for $char(K)\ne 2,3$

> Since $E_i\cong y^2=x^3+c^4 a_ix+c^6 b_i$ and $j(E_i) = 1728 \frac{-4 a_i^3}{-4a_i^3-27b_i^2}=1728 \frac{-4}{-4-27(b_i/a_i)^2 /a_i}$

It suffices to compare $j(E_i)\in K$ and $a_i/b_i\in K^*/K^{*2}$ to find if $E_i\cong E_l$ over $K$

($K^*/K^{*4},K^*/K^{*6}$ in the few degenerate cases $a_ib_i=0$ ie. $j\in 0,1728$)

Comment: Are you sure your link is correct? Silverman's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3668522/21412) seems to be much more in line with what you're talking about. Next, your assumptions about $a_ib_i\neq 0$ are not satisfied for two of the three curves, so it would seem that your post needs a bit more discussion in order to really answer the problem. Finally, if the post you intended to link is all that one needs to solve the problem, you should consider marking this post as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @reuns I see the answer of Silverman's but I can't not find the reference and proof for this. Do you have any proof?

Comment: @Desunkid It is in one of the chapter of Silverman's book AEC. Apply a $c$-isomorphism to obtain that $a_1/b_1=a_2/b_2$ then use that $j(E_1)=j(E_2)$ to obtain that $a_1=a_2,b_1=b_2$. If there is no such $c$-isomorphism $(x,y)\to (c^2x,c^3y)$ (with $c\in K$) then some $c\in K(\sqrt{d})$ works and this $c$ is unique up to $Aut(E_2)$ (which is larger than $(x,y)\to (x,-y)$ only for $j_i\in 0,1728$)

Comment: @reuns. In the case of $j(E)=1728$, what is criterion ?